# How can we add new host key in Function App using ARM-template

Tags: azure-rm-template, azure-automation

what app setting property needs to be added so that new host key will be generated using ARM Template

```
"appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
              "value": "[toLower(variables('functionAppName'))]"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
              "value": "~1"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
              "value": "6.5.0"
            },
            {
              "name": "ConfigurationStorageAccount",
              "value": "[variables('storageAccountName')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "ConfigurationStorageAccountKey",
              "value": "[listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2015-05-01-preview').key2]"
            }
   ]
```

Comment: I dont think you can rotate keys with arm templates?

Comment: Akshay it is not possible to do it from the template. But the template is deployed through powershell i guess? Its possible from powershell. If you need an answer for that i can help

Comment: @HariHaran yes the template is deployed through Powershell. can you please let me know how to do it using PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible to create keys directly from the template. But you can create keys using Powershell / .NET whatever way you are using to deploy the template. Since the `KEY MANAGEMENT API` is just REST.

you can call the below API in your Powershell script to add a new key:

**PUT** `api/sites/{name}[/slots/{slot}]/host/default/{functionkeys|systemkeys}/{keyName}`

```
{
  "properties": {
    "name":"<keyName>",
    "value":<keyValue>"
   }
}
```

More Docs - [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Key-management-API)